# Bistable circuts based on non-linear effects (like breakdown)?

Tags: semiconductors

Is there any known bistable circuits, which utilize parts in non-conventional mode, so that circuit is somewhat simpler than Bistable Multivibrator?

Something like non-destructive breakdown of PN junction comes to my mind....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little "philosophy" about this clever "trick"...

Such elements possess [negative differential resistance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance). They are two types - [S-shaped](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance#An_S-shaped_negative_differential_resistor_.28compare_with_S-shaped_NR.29) (e.g., a neon bulb) and [N-shaped](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance#An_N-shaped_negative_differential_resistor) (e.g., a tunnel diode). To make them operate in a [bistable mode](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance#Bistable_mode), you have to drive an S-shaped NDR with a low resistive voltage source (having an almost vertical IV curve)...

[image: How an S-shaped NDR jumps]

... and to drive an N-shaped NDR with a high resistive current source (having an almost horizontal IV curve):

[image: How an N-shaped NDR jumps]

Under these conditions, negative differential resistors [jump](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Circuit_Idea/Negative_Differential_Resistance#How_the_negative_resistor_.22jumps.22) between their two states, and can serve as Schmitt triggers and latches.

Answer (score 1):

I recall people using neon bulbs as bistable elements.  The ionization voltage is higher than the sustaining voltage.

Basically, the neon bulb is biased somewhere between the ionization and sustaining voltages.  A capacitively-coupled pulse is then introduced.

A positive-going pulse would increase the voltage above the ionization voltage and the bulb would turn ON.  A negative-going pulse will bring the voltage below the sustaining voltage and the bulb turns OFF.

Comment: A similar approach was used with tunnel diodes.

Answer (score 1):

A Diac will achieve bistability .These days Diacs are cheap and easy to find .A common garden variety diac is the BR100 .A common Diac application is triggering Triacs for phase control which is still used in light dimmers .The Diac is not very accurate but it is much better than the neon bulb it replaced.Ne 2 neon bulbs are now getting a bit thin on the ground         .Tunnel diodes are more obscure and I have not experimented with them .They seemed to be more common in vintage electronics mags in the 1960s .